# Arbitrage-free prices in incomplete markets

Tags: option-pricing, books

Hey where I could find theory of option pricing in incomplete markets? I know that there we have not one price, but interval of arbitrage-free prices and I would like to read more about it and I need some references. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Chapter 15 in Arbitrage Theory in Continuous Time by Tomas Björk.

Comment: In the third edition the 15th chapter is called Incomplete Markets.